# OpenCV Android CameraBridgeViewBase how to grab a frame, process it, and draw it, without being interrupted by frame grabs

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, android

I am getting started with OpenCV for Android and I am using the CameraBridgeViewBase class to grab frames. I then call a worker thread to process the frame but I noticed that if my processing takes too long, another frame is grabbed and interrupts my worker thread. How does one get around this? Can you stop the frame grabbing for a period of time? I couldn't find a solution anywhere online!

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to process the frame in

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
    //process before you return the frame
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

your fps will drop but frames will be processed in the same order they are captured